# gulp-ruby-sass undefined variables

Tags: css, sass, gulp

I am using gulp-ruby-sass on windows 8 and it seems like every variable defined within my scss files is not being picked up when it is compiled.

All vars are stored in a settings file like this;

```
// =============================
// Global Default Variables
// =============================

// Global Spacing Values List contains all multiples of the base-spacing-unit value you would like to generate
// within both your padding and margin utility partials.
// Note - Fractions will divide the base-spacing value, and values which are proceeded by an "x"
// multiply the base-spacing value. 0 will create instances which remove spacing.

$global-spacing-values: ("1/2", "1x", "2x", "3x", "0") !default;

// Global Spacing Directions Map contains all the spacing variations which are to be generated
// when calling the generate-spacing mixin.
// Example - t: (top) property called with Margin, would result in mar-t-* attributes being generated.

// Value Key:
// -t- = Top
// -b- = Bottom
// -l- = Left
// -r- = Right
// -e- = Ends  (Top & Bottom)
// -s- = Sides (Left & Right)

$global-spacing-directions: (
    t:  (top),
    b:  (bottom),
    l:  (left),
    r:  (right),
    e:  (top, bottom),
    s:  (left, right)
) !default;

// Set Global Box Sizing Variable to true by default, so it takes effect on all elements.
// Note - Changing this value to false will result in only adding box-sizing to grid-item elements.

$global-box-sizing: true !default;
```

And they are being referenced like so;

```
// =============================
// Base Reset Styling
// =============================

body,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6,
p, blockquote, pre,
dl, dd, ol, ul,
form, fieldset, legend,
table, th, td, caption,
hr {
    margin:  0;
    padding: 0;
}

// If Global Box Sizing Boolean is set to true, add box-sizing to all elements.
// Note - For alternative approach, view grids partial.

@if $global-box-sizing == true {
    * {
        &,
        &:before,
        &:after {
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }
    }
}
```

I am importing the files into a main file like so;

```
@import 'project/settings';
@import 'project/reset';
```

Does anyone know what this issue consists of or has anyone had the same experience?

Thanks

Comment: I had similar experience, not on windows though. File naming was the issue for me. What are your file names? try this:
- remove .css from your file extension, use only .scss extension
- if that still doesn't work, try starting file name with an underscore